# Android: Preference with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

My `OnPreferenceClickListener` creates a new `AlertDialog` like below. When I run the program I get the expection

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

What is wrong in my code?

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    Preference pref= findPreference("text_preference1");
    pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.alert_dialog_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_nein, null).show();

                    //do s.th.
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're getting the `ApplicationContext`. But it shouldn't be used for creating Dialogs.

Instead of `mContext` in `new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)` you should use [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29), which returns the activity associated with a fragment.

Since you are using fragments get the Activity's Context simply by calling the Fragments `getActivity()` method.